# Error 404 al cargar rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error404

Al cargar una ruta en laravel para poder editar un usuario me genera el siguiente error:

```
 404, Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
```

Pero las rutas están previamente definidas

```
Route::get('/home', 'UserController@show')->name('home');
Route::get('/edit', 'UserController@edit')->name('user.edit');
Route::put('/update', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
```

UserController

```
 public function edit()
{
    if(isset($validator)){
        print_r($validator->first('name'));
        die('1');
    }
    $id = 1;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $usuario = User::find($id);
    $tipoDocumento = TipoDocumento::where(['estado' => 1])
        ->orderBy('sigla')
        ->pluck('sigla','id');

    return view('usuario.edit',[
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'tipoDocumento' => $tipoDocumento,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request)
{   
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $usuario = User::find($id);
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$usuario->rules,$usuario->customMessages);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $usuario->name = $request->name;
    $usuario->apellido = $request->apellido;
    $usuario->email = $request->email;
    $usuario->password = $request->password;
    $usuario->sexo = $request->sexo;
    $usuario->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fecha_nacimiento;
    $usuario->tipo_documento_id = $request->tipo_documento_id;
    $usuario->identificacion = $request->identificacion;

    if($request->imagen != ''){
        if(file_exists(public_path('images/usuarios/').$usuario->imagen) == true){
            unlink(public_path('images/usuarios/').$usuario->imagen);
        }
        $time = time();
        $imagen = $time.'.'.$request->imagen->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->imagen->move(public_path('images/usuarios'), $imagen);
        $usuario->imagen = $imagen;
    }

    $usuario->save();

    return redirect(route('home',['id' => $usuario->apellido]));
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál de las rutas que se muestran es la que genera el error?

Comment: Tu formulario debe de tener como método establecido "post": `<form method="post" action="tu-ruta">` Y dentro de tu formulario debes de tener lo siguiente: `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inténtalo así

**ahora modifica el controlador**

considera esto para la funcion edit
estas dandole a $id un valor de 1 y luego otro si te das cuenta no es necesario $id

```
public function edit()
 {   
  $usuario = User::find( Auth::id(););
  $tipoDocumento = TipoDocumento::where('estado', '=', 1)
      ->orderBy('sigla','desc')
      ->pluck('sigla','id');

  return view('usuario.edit',[
      'usuario' => $usuario,
      'tipoDocumento' => $tipoDocumento,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: seguro que esto no esta mal escrito? `$usuario = User::find( Auth::id(););`

Comment: al final da el mismo error 404

Comment: como curiosidad, una accion editar (modificar algo que ya existe) seria con el verbo PUT o PATCH, no con GET. Por otra parte, @shadow tiene razon, sobra un ; en la instruccion. Deberia ser: `$usuario = User::find( Auth::id());`

Comment: Por otra parte, el error te dice que no existe esa url, asi que puede ser que la defincion de las rutas sea erronea, o que intentes acceder a una url que no has definido. Que estas escribiendo en el navegador/postman/? puedes decirnos que url estas intentando acceder?